# Angular2 - set condition once items are visually rendered on page

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list:

```
  <ul *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
            <li>Whatever</li>
   </ul>
```

I then also have a button:

```
<button *ngIf="isMyCondition">Button</button>
```

In the backend my list is being populated such as this:

```
  //Some async http function to get itmes so it takes some time
  myServiceGetItems(null, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error getting items!');
                } else {
                    if (result) {

                        this.items= result;

                    }
                }
                  isMyCondition= true;
            });
```

What is also happening is once the items are retrieved the `isMyCondition` gets set to true. What this does is then makes the button visible. So the button should only be visible once the items are gotten. it works say 95%. What is wrong is the page loads, the items get retrieved and as soon as the items array is set the button appears, but there are a lot of items and it takes about 1 second for the page to render them (longer on a slower mobile device browser), meanwhile for this 1 second the button is visible, but none of the items are showing yet to the user. Is it possible to only make the button visible once the items are received from the server **AND** visually rendered on the page?

Comment: Shouldn't `*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"` be in the `li` tag? Otherwise you're making a new list for every item. If that's the case, not sure if it affects page rendering (assuming that's either an error just in the demo for SO, or that even if so, the size of your list is more of an issue than where the `*ngFor` is).

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping your list in a component, then use the [`AfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/AfterViewInit-interface.html) lifecycle hook to [emit an event to the parent component](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent), which then sets `isMyCondition = true` and shows the button.

**Untested example** (might need some tweaking)

List component:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-list',
  template: `
     <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">Whatever</li>
     </ul>
  `
})
export class MyList implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input()  items: Array;
  @Output() onListLoaded = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  ngAfterViewInit () {

    this.onListLoaded.emit(true); 

  }

}
```

Parent component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// Don't forget to import the MyList child component from wherever it lives
// Same for the service.

@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent',
  template: `
     <my-list items="items | async" (onListLoaded)="showButton()"></my-list>
     <button *ngIf="isMyCondition">Button</button>
  `,
  directives: [MyList],
  services: [myService]
})
export class MyParent implements OnInit {

  items: Array = [];
  isMyCondition: boolean = false;

  constructor (private _service: myService) {
  }

  ngOnInit () {

    _service.myServiceGetItems(); // Or whenever you want to get the items

  }

  showButton() {
    this.isMyCondition = true;
  }

}
```